# Quiet hours "no vibration" not affecting SMS notifications

Tags: vibration, cyanogenmod

Running CM11 (Android 4.4).

When i turn Quiet Hours on, with the option "Disable vibrations" checked, my phone still vibrate on incoming SMS.

How can i achieve the following state, with Quiet Hours:

- Low sound volume for everything
- No vibration for anything

Thank you for help :)